# CONCAT with JOIN: create only one row per id although multiple rows for id

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, left-join

I'm using `MySQL`.

I have the following sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table1` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `column1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `my_table1` (`id`, `column1`, `column2`) VALUES
(1, 'George', 'something'),
(2, 'Peter', 'anything');

CREATE TABLE `my_table2` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `column1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `my_table2` (`id`, `column1`) VALUES
(1, 'DDD'),
(1, 'HHH'),
(1, 'FFF'),
(2, 'LLL'),
(2, 'TTT');
```

I want to merge all columns of `my_table1` into one new column called `new_column`. Additionally I also want to merge the `column1` from `my_table2` to `new_column` where `my_table1.id = my_table2.id`.

If there are multiple rows with `my_table1.id = my_table2.id` in `my_table2` I want to merge them all in `new_column` in the same row.

So, expected output for my tables is the following:

| id | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | George something DDD HHH FFF |
| 2 | Peter anything LLL TTT |

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT my_table1.id
     , CONCAT_WS(' ', my_table1.column1, my_table1.column2, my_table2.column1) AS new_column 
  FROM my_table1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table2 
    ON my_table1.id = my_table2.id;
```

I got the following result:

| id | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | George something DDD |
| 1 | George something HHH |
| 1 | George something FFF |
| 2 | Peter anything LLL |
| 2 | Peter anything TTT |

[Here you can see a MySQL fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pqpfBsPhseggVszaJXUQoA/1)

What can I do to receive the expected output?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry My question is already solved but I'm still wondering what exactly you mean. From now on I'll use tables here in SO instead of a screenshoot from `phpMyAdmin`. I didn't know it's possible, till today. I updated my question with these tables. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Strawberry I think I got what you meant: In future, I'll use https://www.db-fiddle.com.

Comment: @Strawberry I updated my question again. Is this the right way now or is there still something I should improve?

Comment: I've reformatted your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `JOIN` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT
    my_table1.id,
    CONCAT_WS (' ', my_table1.column1, my_table1.column2, GROUP_CONCAT(my_table2.column1 SEPARATOR ' ')) AS new_column
FROM my_table1
LEFT JOIN my_table2
    ON my_table1.id = my_table2.id
GROUP BY my_table1.id
```

[Here's a fiddle of the working query.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2hoCtBgbwWsp75TjD5NPU/2)

Comment: For me, this doesn't change anything, it's till the same.

Comment: @David . . . I thought the big result set at the end was your *desired* results.  Your question is rather hard to follow but I found the expected results and fixed the answer.

Comment: If there's e.g. an `id=3` in `my_table1` but no `id=3` in `my_table2`, `id=3` won't appear at all in the newly created table/column. Why that?

Comment: @David . . . Because the `JOIN` doesn't match.  You can switch to `LEFT JOIN` if you need.